# How To Call Multiple Collections From Firestore in one Field - React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i want to call multiple collections from firebase so i can display items from those collections to my home page, i have two collections `salati` and `recipes` and they have their own documents in there but i dont know if its possible to call the in single field.

**Heres how my code that returns fine from one collection**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('salati');
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      RecipeArr: [],
    };
```

**And heres how i tried to get multiple but didnt work**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('salati, recipes');

    or

    this.firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('salati', 'recipes');
    
    or
    this.firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('salati' 'recipes');

    or
    
    this.firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('salati'),('recipes');
```

None of the above works. Is there a solution to it or i need some different declarations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data loading operation from Firestore can only read data from a single collection, or from all collections with the same name. In your scenario you will have to load the results from both collections separately and then combine the results in your application code.